# C++ and Visual Studio error - no suitable conversion function from "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>" to "int" exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cout

Visual Studio is going crazy on me recently, and gives me the error in the subject when all I did was a simple cout...

CODE:

```
// Lang.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main{
    cout << "hi";
}
```

Comment: Also, the semicolon after "hi" is highlighted, and says "expected a }"...

Comment: You're missing a parameter list `()` for `main`, it gets treated as (syntactically invalid) [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) for variable of type `int`.

Comment: *Visual Studio is going crazy on me recently* It probably needs its meds :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int main{
>     cout << "hi";
> }
> ```

Due to the possibility of initialising objects in C++ with the `{}` syntax, your compiler probably interprets this code as an attempt to create a global `int` variable called `main`, initialised with the result of `std::ostream::operator<<`, a member function which returns a reference to the `std::ostream` itself.

It's as if you had written:

```
double some_variable { cout << "hi" }
```

Or:

```
double some_variable { cout }
```

`std::ostream` is actually `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`. And that type is not compatible with `int`.

The only thing which is strange is why the `;` after `"hi"` does not immediately cause the compiler to stop trying; but you don't say which compiler version and which options you are using.

In any case, all of those facts finally result in the error message:

> ```
> no suitable conversion function from “std::basic_ostream<char,
>     std::char_traits<char>>” to “int” exists
> ```

and in:

> Also, the semicolon after "hi" is highlighted, and says "expected a }"

Solution: make `main` a function:

```
int main() {
    cout << "hi";
}
```